# How does the for event in pygame.event.get() in python work?

Tags: python, pygame

My problem is that during the execution of this loop
hundreds of events may be happening and for every event
it is yielding an Event object.... So, How is the loop
able to finish and the interpreter come out of the loop?

Comment: My point was that what if someone keep on moving the mouse and keep on pressing keys on the keyboard......pygame.event.get() will keep on yielding Event objects for each and every event. So how will the interpreter come out of that list of hundreds of objects..

Comment: it gets only the current events that are in the event queue

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by event queue..... What is an event queue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events are queued. When a new event occurs, it is added to the end of the queue. When [`pygame.event.get`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) is called, the events currently in the queue are returned and the queue is emptied. See [`pygame.event.get`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html):

> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue.

New events that occur while the event loop is executed are added to the queue. You will get these events the next time [`pygame.event.get`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)  is called in the next frame.